# Does ng-repeat recreate all child DOM elements when new data is appended to the array?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive that handles infinity loading of blog posts as the user scrolls down.

I'm wondering how AngularJS handles the addition of new blog posts when the feed is rendered using ng-repeat.

For example

```
<article ng-repeat="post in posts">
       // stuff...
</article>
```

Are all the articles recreated each time `posts` is updated with new posts? Assuming that only new posts are appended to the array.

Is ng-repeat smart enough to only create the new posts?

I worry that after the user has scrolled down for a long period the refresh rate will get slower as ng-repeat recreates all the blogs each time new ones are fetched from the server.

Comment: Yes, it caches dom elements, it will not re-create the ones that are already there. The performance of ng-repeat really just depends on what you are doing inside of it. (How many items are in data binds, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat, by default, tracks the items of the collection by their `$id()`: angular associates an identity to every item, and if you add a node to the collection, the elements already associated to the existing items of the collection won't be recreated.

OTOH, if your strategy is to recreate a new collection of items every time you scroll down, the new items will have a different identity (even if they represent the same post as before), and angular will recreate all the DOM elements. That's what `track by` is for: it allows telling ng-repeat how to associate DOM elements with items of the collection. You could for example use `track by id`, and an element previously associated with an item with id 3 will be preserved by ng-repeat and be associated to the new item having the id 3.

Comment: +1 thanks, this is good to know. I saw those IDs added to items in the debugger and now it makes sense what they're for.